# Java HTTP Get Request

Tags: java, service, get, request

I need to make one HTTP GET Request to a Java Web Service:
I'm making this request:

```
http://127.0.0.1:8080/MyService/services/service?method=myMethod&a=&b=test&startDate=2011-03-10 10:00&endDate=2011-03-10 19:00
```

When I Debug my app the parameters come with the values switched. I already tried to encode the startDate and endDate parameters but the result is the same.

What am i doing wrong?

Comment: Can you show the code you are using to construct the URL as well as the code you are using to parse it?

Answer (score 1):

You should encode your URLs so they don't contain spaces. This could be your problem.  See http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/net/URLEncoder.html

Answer (score 0):

As @Mirkules says, you should encode the spaces and colons in the parameter values ... *even if you don't think it makes any difference*!

Apart from that, maybe your servlet code is expecting `Request.getParameters()` to deliver the parameters in the order that they appear in the URL.  This is not the case.  If order of the parameters is significant, you need to parse the query string yourself.  (Or consider fixing your web API so that the query parameter order is irrelevant.)